# I want to count the unique host out of timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas columns in my temp pandas dataframe I want to count by the date time for a unique host for in a same day inside of my dataframe the log file look like this

```
10.216.113.172 - - [04/Sep/2009:02:57:16 -0700] "GET /images/filmpics/0000/0053/quietman2.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 1077924
10.211.47.159 - - [03/Sep/2009:22:19:49 -0700] "GET /quietman4.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 212
10.211.47.159 - - [22/Aug/2009:12:58:27 -0700] "GET /assets/img/closelabel.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.216.113.172 - - [14/Jan/2010:03:09:17 -0800] "GET /images/filmmediablock/229/Shinjuku5.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 443005
10.211.47.159 - - [15/Oct/2009:21:21:58 -0700] "GET /assets/img/banner/ten-years-banner-grey.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.216.113.172 - - [12/Aug/2009:05:57:55 -0700] "GET /about-us/people/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10773
10.211.47.159 - - [24/Aug/2009:13:16:26 -0700] "GET /assets/img/search-button.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.211.47.159 - - [03/Sep/2009:21:30:27 -0700] "GET /images/newspics/0000/0017/Mike5_thumb.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.211.47.159 - - [15/Oct/2009:20:30:43 -0700] "GET /images/filmpics/0000/0057/quietman4.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.211.47.159 - - [11/Aug/2009:20:34:44 -0700] "GET /assets/img/search-button.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

I have those timestamps(03/Sep/2009:22:19:49 -0700) and hosts(10.211.47.159 ) in my dataframe temp the desired output is [2,1,1,2,1,1] the -0700 is what we have to subtract to the time and the time have to push back to one if went back a day.
heres my code

```
but my output is [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] may someone help
temp = pandas.DataFrame()
temp['timestamp'] = Mainpanda['timestamp']
temp['host'] = Mainpanda['host']

temp['timestamp'] = 
pandas.to_datetime(temp['timestamp'], 
format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
temp['timestamp'] = temp['timestamp'] - pandas.Timedelta(hours=7)

counts = temp.groupby('timestamp')['host'].nunique().reset_index()

counts = counts.sort_values(by='timestamp')

counts = counts['host'].tolist()

print(counts)
```

Comment: Why do you have a -0800 as timezone and all other to -0700?

Comment: is just small piece among the other datas others have -0600,-0400

Comment: Im also thinking how to change that part 2, I dont know how I can get the -7 out of datatimestamp

Comment: If you have multiple timezone, it could be interesting to convert all to UTC or to your local timezone.

Comment: Yes i have to - all of them by 7 or 6 or 8 but I think i found how I solve that problem but I just dont know why it displaying 1,1,1,1,1

Answer (score 0):

First convert to DatetimeIndex then align all datetime to UTC: it's important to have the same timezone to process correctly your data:

```
import pandas as pd

temp['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['timestamp'], format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
temp['ts_utc'] = pd.DatetimeIndex([dt.tz_convert('UTC') for dt in temp['timestamp']])

visits = (temp.groupby(['host', pd.Grouper(key='ts_utc', freq='D')]).size()
              .to_frame('visit').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> visits

             host                    ts_utc  visit
0   10.211.47.159 2009-08-12 00:00:00+00:00      1
1   10.211.47.159 2009-08-22 00:00:00+00:00      1
2   10.211.47.159 2009-08-24 00:00:00+00:00      1
3   10.211.47.159 2009-09-04 00:00:00+00:00      2
4   10.211.47.159 2009-10-16 00:00:00+00:00      2
5  10.216.113.172 2009-08-12 00:00:00+00:00      1
6  10.216.113.172 2009-09-04 00:00:00+00:00      1
7  10.216.113.172 2010-01-14 00:00:00+00:00      1
```